# Testing for a common intersection of p linear regression lines

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, linear-model

> I'm trying to derive a test for testing if p regression lines have a common point of intersection.

Let the p regression lines intersect at a point $(x_0,y_0)$. We are to test: $H_0: a_1+b_1*x_0 = a_2+b_2*x_0=...=a_p+b_p*x_0$ against $H_1:$not $H_0$.

Cond. SS due to error= Min (under $H_0)$ wrt $a_i, b_i \forall i \sum_{i=1}^{p} \sum_{j=1}^{n_i} (y_{ij}-a_i-b_i*x_0)^2$

Let $S$ denote the double summation to be minimised.
$\forall i=1(1)p$,
$\frac{\delta S}{\delta a_i}=0, \frac{\delta S}{\delta b_i}=0$ yield the same equation:$\bar y_{io}=a_i+b_i*x_0$ so I'm not sure how to proceed further to determine $\hat a_i, \hat b_i.$ Please help.

Comment: Begin by describing the data.  In particular, what--if any--are the relationships among the data used to estimate these regression lines?  For instance, do you have multiple responses for a fixed set of explanatory values $x_0,$ or do you have $p$ different regression problems altogether? Do you make any assumptions about how those problems might be interrelated, such as having the same error variance?